# why the integral of $g'(x)/g(x)$ is $\ln(|x|)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, integrating-factor

To the integrating factor method for differential equations I have to make a step where the integral of  $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$   is   $\ln(|x|)$.

I don't understand how this is derived.

Comment: Don't you mean the derivative of $\ln(g(x))$?

Comment: $$\mathrm{D}_x\{g'(x)/g(x)\}=\frac{g''(x)g(x)-g'(x)^2}{g(x)^2}$$
$$\int\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\ln(|g(x)|)+C$$

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't think OP will know the differential operator notation

Comment: In that case it's the same as the classical $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$, just easier to type.

Comment: @JamesO'dare i see understand now what i did wrong. Its actually not that hard. ill edit my question. I ment the integral in stead of the derivative